# How to setup wifi on raspberry pi with username and password on Android Things using adb shell

Tags: android-things

I have a raspberry pi running an older version of Android things that is capable of connecting to my wifi. I copied and inserted the wpa_supplicant file from that pi to another pi with an updated version of android things but the new pi is unable to connect to the wifi. Am I missing something here?

Comment: Does it try to connect? Possibly you need to add the interface to ``networking/interfaces`` first or install some package which was installed on the previous pi.

Comment: might be helpful to know what the old and new versions are

Comment: The old version was devpreview 4 and the current is 6.1. I can connect to wifi without a username. But it does not try to connect with the wifi that needs the identity with the wpa_supplicant file with the network configuration.

Answer (score 1):

There is [a guide](https://developer.android.com/things/hardware/wifi-adb.html) on how to do this.

In the adb shell you can execute this command:

```
am startservice \
-n com.google.wifisetup/.WifiSetupService \
-a WifiSetupService.Connect \
-e ssid my-ssid \
-e passphrase my-passphrase
```

Comment: My network requires a username and passphrase. As far as I know, I can't establish a connection with an identity using that command. I have to manually add the connection in my wpa_supplicant.conf file, but it doesn't seem to be working.

Comment: You may be able to use the WifiManager to programmatically add a new Wi-Fi network with that information. Here's some code that adds a new network to the wi-fi manager: https://github.com/ITVlab/Enterprise-Wi-Fi/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/felkertech/ussenterprise/fragments/EnterpriseFragment.java